# How to use R to make hierarchical tree graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tree, data-visualization

I have a data frame that I'd like to plot in a particular way. The example dummy data frame is below

| Sample | Cell Type | Gene Expression | DNA Methylation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | HSC | 25 | 0.75 |
| 002 | MPP | 50 | 0.90 |

Would I be able to graph it using clusters where the size of the circle represents the variable gene expression (large circles meaning higher gene expression) and a colour gradient for the second variable (DNA methylation) where red could mean high DNA methylation, white could mean somewhat high and blue meaning low. The part of the graph is that the cells would need to be related to one another through arrows showing their relationships with one another.

Attached is an image of what I'm trying to recreate (the example is made in javascript which I have no experience in) with the added feature of a colour gradient.

[image: Example plot using Javascript]

So far in R I've tried to use ggplot but there doesn't seem to be a perfect graph that can show 2 numerical variables and one categorical variable (cell type) besides a correlative colour-coded scatter plot, which I don't want since the categorical variables have tree like relationships with one another which I'd like to emphasized.

Highly appreciate if anyone has any suggestions how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

why not use data.tree ? This should fit most of your needs
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).